# What is the working of Class A , ClassB and Class C amplifiers?

Tags: analog, power-electronics

Please describe conceptually the working of Class A, Class B and Class C amplifiers.Having problems understanding them.

Comment: Did you even try to look around for the answer?

Comment: Go through MICROELECTRONIC CIRCUITS by SEDRA SMITH.

Comment: What research have you done to try and understand these concepts? What level are you at in your understanding? How can an answer be provided that matches your needs if we don't know these things?

Answer (score 9):

I'll make this brief because there is lots out there about this and repeating it here would be pointless.

**Class A**: Both the high and low side drivers are on at least somewhat over the whole output range.  In the general case, they are on linearly over the output range, each with opposite polarity.

**Class B**: Each high and low driver is only on when the signal is on its side, from the midpoint on.  This wastes less power than class A, but making the two drivers hand off without a glitch at the midpoint is tricky.

**Class C**: Resonance-based amplifier, as is commonly used in radio transmitters.  Due to the resonance and energy storage in the resonant circuit, the driver produces a single pulse once per output cycle.  This can be very efficient since the driver is either always full on or full off in the ideal case.